# Why does $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{ikna} e^{-ilna} = N\delta_{kl}$?

Tags: summation

Why does $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{ikna} e^{-ilna} = N\delta_{kl}$?

I tried to solve this question but I could not really proceed. This summation sign is making this difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This isn't right. Suppose $N=1$, $k=2$, $l=1$. It follows that the sum is $e^0$, which is $1$ but the right hand side is $0$. If $N=2$, then one would get instead $1+e^{ia(k-l)}$ for the left hand, and $2 \delta_{kl}$ for the right. When $k=l$, this is true, but when $k=l+1$, one gets $1+e^{ia}$ on the left and $0$ on the right. $e^{ia}$ is certainly almost always not $-1$. Is $a$ supposed to equal $\pi$? Where did you find this formula?

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
s(k, l, N, a)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{ikna} e^{-ilna}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{i(k-l)na}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (e^{i(k-l)a})^n\\
&=\dfrac{1-(e^{i(k-l)a})^N}{1-e^{i(k-l)a}}\\
&=\dfrac{1-e^{i(k-l)Na}}{1-e^{i(k-l)a}}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$s(k, l, N, a) = 0$
if 
$(k-l)Na = 2\pi m$
or
$a = \dfrac{2\pi m}{(k-l)N}
$
for some $m$.

You might want to investigate
$a = \pi r/s$
for integral $r, s$.

Nothing much here, really.